# How many distinct straight lines can be formed that are given by equation $ax + by = 0$, where $a$, $b$ are numbers from the set {$0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7$}?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

My answer is 37.

- If $a = 0$, then only possible equation is $ y= 0$
- If $b = 0$, then only possible equation is $ x= 0$

For {$1,2,3,4,5,6,7$}, possible pairs are $7*7 = 49$. Therefore, $49+2 = 51$ equations in total but it includes several repeats:

- $(1,1), ..., (7,7)$ are all $x + y = 0$. Therefore, $51 - 6 = 45$
- $(1,2), (2,4), (3,6)$ are all $x + 2y = 0$. Therefore, $45 - 2 = 43$
- $(1,3), (2,6)$ are all $x + 3y = 0$. Therefore, $43 - 1 = 42$
- $(2,1), (4,2), (6,3)$ are all $2x + y = 0$. Therefore, $42 - 2 = 40$
- $(2,3),(4,6)$ are all $2x + 3y = 0$. Therefore, $40 - 1 = 39$
- $(3,1),(6,2)$ are all $3x + 1y = 0$. Therefore, $39 - 1 = 38$
- $(3,2),(6,4)$ are all $3x + 2y = 0$. Therefore, $38 - 1 = 37$

Thus, we can make $37$ unique equations.

Is my reasoning correct? Is there any generalized/better method available?

Comment: Look up bezouts lemma. It maybe helpful. It may also be noted that the relation "two pairs of coefficients give same line" is an equivalence relation. So, you're asking the number of disjoint subsets formed by the equivalence relation.

Comment: For sake of simplification set $a=0$ then you have eight values of $y$, and put $b=0$, then you have eight values of $x$.  This makes defining the equivalence relation pretty simple :  In your relation, a pair $(a,b) $ is related to a pair $(a',b')$ if $\frac{a}{a'} = \frac{b}{b'}$. You could also think of it as the determinant condition s $\begin{vmatrix}  a & b \\ a' &b' \end{vmatrix}=0$

Comment: Error in the above comment: If you set $a=0$, then you only have seven values of $y$ and vice versa not eight. As $(0,0)$ is not really a line

Comment: Consider the subset of all prime numbers $\{1,2,3,5,7\}$, now for this subset each possible pair without repeating terms you choose is a unique line. So, $\binom{5}{2}$, so there is immediately we get there at least ten lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$37$ is the right answer. Here is how I approached it -

The given equation is $ax + by = 0$; $a, b \in (0, 7)$

$(a)$ Let's start with $a = 1$. All *eight* values of $b$ give unique lines. Similarly for $b = 1$, we get *eight* unique lines but $a = b = 1$ is counted twice. That leads to $15$ unique lines.

$(b)$ Then for $~2 \leq a, b \leq 7$, we choose  $a$ and $b$ such that they are relatively prime, otherwise they would give lines already counted in $(a)$.

So,
For $a = 5, 7$, we have *five* value of $b$.
For $a = 3$, we have *four* values of $b$.
For $a = 2, 4$, we have *three* values of $b$.
For $a = 6$, we have *two* value of $b$.

That leads to number of unique lines as $~15 + 22 = 37$